# DateTime being weird

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

How come

```
w.WriteLine(Program.RegisterList[i].DateTime);
```

Writes : `11/20/2013 01:46:31 PM`

But

```
w.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(Program.RegisterList[i].DateTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());
```

Writes `20/11/2013 1:46:31 PM`

? Isn't invariant culture supposed to make it MM/DD/YY? I would like to use the invariant culture method incase a date slips by in DD/MM/YY format.

Thanks!

Edit: I should mention `Program.RegisterList[i].DateTime` is a string.

Edit2:

```
MessageBox.Show("11/20/2013 01:46:31 PM");
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToDateTime("11/20/2013 01:46:31 PM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());
```

Comment: What is the type of `Program.RegisterList[i].DateTime`? Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Sure, I'll put one together. One sec

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited it into my question

Comment: First messagebox shows MM/DD/YY, second one converts to DD/MM/YY for some reason

Comment: You are displaying the date in your own culture, not invariant.  You only *parsed* the string using invariant.

Comment: Hans is correct - to use `CultureInvariant`, you should pass it in the `IFormatProvider` in the trailing `ToString()` method - by using the default no-arg method, you are using you're own culture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 w.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(Program.RegisterList[i].DateTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString());
```

You confused yourself by writing code you can't understand anymore.  A simple rewrite of that one honking statement:

```
string s = Program.RegisterList[i].DateTime;
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
w.WriteLine(dt);
```

Which should now make it obvious that you are **not** using InvariantCulture to display the date, it uses the default culture.  Which on your machine puts the day first.

Always write readable code, it is *not* slower.

Comment: @HansPassant Ahh, I misunderstood what Invarient culture did. How would I go about changing a datetime into `MM/DD/YY HH MM SS AM/PM` format?

Comment: If you want a specific format, you can use a custom format string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

`CultureInvariant` only guarantees that the format won't change across cultures - it should not be used to display data, only to persist data. If you're concerned about how a string is displayed, you should use a specific culture that displays how you want. [More from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Having said that, I'm not sure what you mean by a "date slipping by" in a different format. Are you reading a list of dates, and some are in different format? If so, I'm afraid `CultureInvariant` is not the answer.